# Angular 9 - Property Binding with undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9, property-binding

I have a component called CustomTextBox

In my CustomTextBox.ts ,  written as

```
@Input('id') _id:string
@Input('class') _class:string
```

In my CustomTextBox.htm, By Using Property Binding, written as

```
<textarea [id]="_id" [class]="_class"></textarea>
```

I can able to call the component as any one of the below option from app component

```
<CustomTextBox></CustomTextBox>
  <CustomTextBox id="sampleid"></CustomTextBox>
  <CustomTextBox class="sampleid"></CustomTextBox>
```

id and class are optional

But when Called `<CustomTextBox></CustomTextBox>` Generating the code as below

```
<CustomTextBox id="undefined" class="undefined"></CustomTextBox>
```

how can i make property as optional if the values are null or undefined

Stackbitz Solution

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v1sybw

Comment: Have you seen the edit I made on my post with a new solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to write this in your template

```
<textarea [attr.id]="_id?_id:null" [attr.class]="_class?_class:null"></textarea>
```

This will check if your `_id` and your `_class` are set, if not the return value will be `null`, this will have the effect of removing the attribute and so not showing an undefined value.

Comment: Thank you Alexis, I tried but still showing the value as undefined

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz with your issue please

Comment: you can find from https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v1sybw

Comment: Alexis , Except for the  "id" everything looks good, only for the id it shows the value as null

Comment: That's weird, on the stackblitz this change do the job :( and if you try `''` instead of null ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a default value to both your `@Input` just like any other property:

```
@Input('id') _id:string = "defaultId";
@Input('class') _class:string = "defaultClass"
```

When an `@input` value is `undefined` it will take the default value.

If you want to completely hide the `CustomTextBox` in case no `_id` or `_class` are provided you can try:

```
showTextBox: boolean = false;

ngOnInit(): void {
    if(_id !== undefined && _class !== undefined){
         showTextBox= true;
    }
}
```

and in your html file:

```
<CustomTextBox *ngIf ="showTextBox"></CustomTextBox>
```

Comment: Thank you charbel, But to add a default value , I don't think it's good practice, and  if I use ngIf control will be invisible if i am not passing the any of the value

Comment: Can you elaborate? what do you want to happen to the `CustomTextBox` in case of `undefined` values?